# Python :: Intersecting lists of strings gone wrong

Tags: python, list

I am trying to intersect lists of sentences divided into strings:

```
    user = ['The', 'Macbeth', 'Tragedie'] #this list
    plays = []

    hamlet = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-hamlet.txt')
    macbeth = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-macbeth.txt')
    caesar = gutenberg.sents('shakespeare-caesar.txt')
    plays.append(hamlet)
    plays.append(macbeth)
    plays.append(caesar)

    shakespeare = list(chain.from_iterable(plays)) # with this list
```

'shakespeare' prints as follows:

`[['[', 'The', 'Tragedie', 'of', 'Hamlet', 'by', 'William', 'Shakespeare', '1599', ']'], ['Actus', 'Primus', '.'], ['Scoena', 'Prima', '.'], ['Enter', 'Barnardo', 'and', 'Francisco', 'two', 'Centinels', '.']...['FINIS', '.'], ['THE', 'TRAGEDIE', 'OF', 'IVLIVS', 'CaeSAR', '.']]`

```
    bestCount = 0
    for sent in shakespeare:
        currentCount = len(set(user).intersection(sent))
        if currentCount > bestCount:
            bestCount = currentCount
            answer = ' '.join(sent)
    return ''.join(answer).lower(), bestCount
```

`return`, however, does not intersect right, that is, "hamlet" intersects with "macbeth"...

`('the tragedie of hamlet , prince of denmarke .', 3)`

where is the bug?

Comment: That `shakespeare` structure looks awfully strange and poorly constructed. A list of lists with members in the inner list like `'['`?? What's wrong with a simpler approach where you have a sentence that is just a string of words, you split it with `split` (maybe filter out punctuation), and call `set(that_list).intersect(set(other_list_like_it))`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist `sent()` is a NLTK method -a toolkit for computational linguistics, which fetches tagged words and etc. in this case, the send fetches sentences divided by strings. however, I would like to order the corpus by author, and not by plays.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Finding sentences common to each play? Finding occurrences of specific words?

Comment: finding occurrences of words used by a user and return the corpus sentence with most ocurrences.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you should use sets at all. When you convert to sets all your occurrences are collapsed into one member and you lose track of that information. Should be something like `member.lower() in map(str.lower, sent)` to test and you could use the `count` list method for number of occurrences.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist nice sir, why don't you answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you should be using sets here. The most obvious problem is that you care about the number of occurrences of a word in a sentence (which starts life as a list), and by converting to a set you collapse all repeated words down to one occurrence, losing that information.

I would suggest rather converting each sentence's members into lowercase, like so:

```
mapped = map(str.lower, sentence)  # may want list(map(...)) if on Py3
```

Initialize a dict of counts like this:

```
In [6]: counts = {word.lower(): 0 for word in user}

In [7]: counts
Out[7]: {'macbeth': 0, 'the': 0, 'tragedie': 0}
```

Then as you loop over the sentences, you can do something like this:

```
In [8]: for word in counts:
   ...:     counts[word] = max(counts[word], mapped.count(word))
   ...:

In [9]: counts
Out[9]: {'macbeth': 0, 'the': 1, 'tragedie': 1}
```

I just used one example sentence, but you get the idea. At the end you'll have the maximum number of times the user's word appeared in a sentence. You can make the data structure a little more complex or use an if statement test if you want to also keep the sentence it occurred the most times in.

Good luck!